# iot modules for wifi sta/ap concurrency inspired by high end android devices (detailed question list given below)

Tags: wifi, android

so i'm looking to form a wireless mesh network so that when one node doesnt work i can reset the route. for this im looking for a module that hosts wifi as well as hotspot simultaneously. now i know that it is possible as some mobiles support wifi and hotspot at the same time on the same band (5ghz, my mobile supports this and i've tested it)

so my questions are:

1. how does a mobile make it possible to support same band concurrency?
2. is there any iot module which supports concurrency? if no then is there any other way i.e. combination of devices that can make this possible?
3. or is there an other wireless technology that can enable a wireless mesh network?